# How do I align the origin rotation to the clear rotation of an object?

Tags: origin

How can I align the origin's rotation to the "obvious" rotation of an object?

In the picture, you can see that the origin rotation isn't the same as the rotation of the empty:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Set `Transformation orientation` to `local` to align the origin with the object. This didn't solve what I really wanted to do which was to rotate the empty on the *local* x-axis. It ended up rotating crooked.

What I had to do was press `r` `x` then `x` again to rotate on *local* x-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a *custom transformation orientation*.
That will allow you to create new transformation orientation depends on edges or faces.

Keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>

Here is a link to a quick tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaL05JYEP9o

Answer (score 0):

I think you can press the object and click numpad "."

If not, you can go to model and shift click with the 3d cursor option enabled. That will move the 3D cursor which is the rotation origin.